# how to fix "go not root owned"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, root

I installed go on ubuntu 16.04 from the archive and tried to test my installation by issuing the command `go` on my terminal. It keeps prompting me `/ not root-owned 1000:0`.

I installed go on `/usr/local` folder and also included it into my path as instructed on the official golang installation. I removed go and tried to install it again, but found the same result. It sounds more of a linux root permission issue, but I have no clue how to fix it. I tried other commands that I installed from archive and they work perfectly fine. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'from the archive'? How exactly did you install Go?

Comment: Just a wild guess: there was [this bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19883) in npm that may have caused this. If it did, there are likely to be more system directories that are no longer owner by root; you should fix that asap as it is a serious security risk.

Answer (score 15):

It seems to complain that the system root directory `/` has the wrong owner. This is a security problem because you don't want to have regular users changing system files at will. It looks like you changed this on purpose at some point in the past; change it back, or reinstall your system if you have wrecked more permissions than just this one.

```
sudo chown root /
```

For the record, the proper way to give yourself *limited* system access is to use `sudo`.  Add yourself to `sudoers` (usually this is already set up by the OS installer on any reasonably consumer-oriented Linux distro) and when you need privileges for something, run that command with `sudo`.

Comment: You may also have to run `sudo chown root:root /` if the owner group of `/` is messed up.

Comment: i also had to run `sudo chgrp root /var/` as i messed t up before lol

Comment: I had to do it using `sudo chown root -R /`

Comment: @alper You have wrecked other unrelated things by doing that.

Answer (score 9):

Simple, in the command line:

```
sudo chown root:root /
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the root permission issue I had, I also found that I installed go using snap to: `snap install --classic go`, which wasn't a good idea. I was also unable to remove the go folder in `/snap`, even as root. I now reinstall my system and hopefully the issue will be solved.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo chown root /var
```

This will solve your problem