# VS code doesn't open any more

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code on ubuntu 18.04. since this morning I couldn't open my vs code. When I try open it in terminal I get this error:

```
code .
/ not root-owned 0:100
```

How can I solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITscM.png)

Comment: did you try sudo code?

Comment: Yes, but the result is same.

Comment: are you login as admin or a local user?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506159/how-to-fix-go-not-root-owned

Comment: this should work sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you don't own root.

Try running:

```
sudo chown root:root /
```