# Problem running Android Studio on Ubuntu 20.04 terminal

Tags: android-studio, installation, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run latest android studio IDE that I installed through Snap on Ubuntu 20.04 using terminal but am presented with the following error: "/ not root-owned 1023:1023"

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and running using root privileges but it doesn't seem to help. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix "go not root owned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506159/how-to-fix-go-not-root-owned)

Comment: Nope, I've tried the suggestions with no success